# Type Mismatch Error with For Loop and Tuple TreeSet

Tags: scala

I'm a new Scala programmer and I've run into a problem. I'm writing a function to get the number of When I try to get the value from my for loop (Near the bottom encapsulated in an If/Else statement), it gives me a Type Mismatch Error. I'm expecting a TreeSet tuple with a String and an Int (scala.collection.mutable.TreeSet[(String, Int)]) but it says it returns a Unit.

Here are my instructions for this, and I believe if I resolve this error it should work.

"Note: the return type is a TreeSet of tuples
that have the type (String, Int). For example, given the list of people List(“tom”,
“ann”, “rob”, “rob”, “ann”, “tom”, “pat”, “rob” “pat”, “tom”) your function should
return TreeSet((tom,3), (rob,3)). Note: that there is a tie for the biggest crook, 
you must return all the biggest crooks in the set. A list where names only appear
one time return a empty TreeSet."

***The function "crooks" and "a" are both defined in other places not shown.

```
  def biggestCrooks(people: List[String]): TreeSet[(String,Int)] = {

    val crooksListed = crooks(people).toList //Runs my one function that gives me the
                                         // list of criminals with more than one offense

    var numCounted = new Array[Int](crooksListed.size) // Array to hold the number of times a person name 
                                                       //appears

    for(nameIndex <- 0 until crooksListed.size){ // Counts the number of times a name appears
      val counter = people.count(_.equals(crooksListed(nameIndex))) //Stores that name in the array
      numCounted(nameIndex) = counter //Stores the num in the index associated with the name

     }
    var largestValue = numCounted.max // Largest value in the array
    val numValues = numCounted.count(_ == largestValue) // Number of times the value appears
    var indeces : Set[Int] = Set()
    var completeList : TreeSet[(String, Int)] = TreeSet() // Completed list of all names / values

    if(numValues > 1){// Used JIC there are multiple instances of numValues
    for(i <- 0 until numCounted.length){ //If there are multiple instances, find the indeces of them
      if(numCounted(i) == largestValue)
        indeces(i)                       //add the index to the array
    }
    val wow = indeces.toList //Converts a mutable Set to an immutable list
     for(i <- 0 until wow.size){ //iterate through the indeces and associate with names
       completeList.map(crooksListed(wow(i)), wow(i)) //Maps the values to the completeList TreeSet
       //Supposed to solve problem with mismatched types

     } 
    }
    else{

      completeList.map(i => (crooksListed(numCounted.indexOf(largestValue)), largestValue)) //Maps the values to the TreeSet
    }
  }// end biggestCrook

println(biggestCrooks(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, every statement in scala is an *expression* and every *expression* has a return *type* and should *something to return*. In your sample first branch of if else statement returns **nothing**, in scala it means *Unit* type:

```
if(numValues > 1){// Used JIC there are multiple instances of numValues
  for(i <- 0 until numCounted.length){ //If there are multiple instances, find the indeces of them
    if(numCounted(i) == largestValue)
      indeces(i)                       //add the index to the array
  }
  val wow = indeces.toList //Converts a mutable Set to an immutable list
  for(i <- 0 until wow.size){ //iterate through the indeces and associate with names
    completeList.map(crooksListed(wow(i)), wow(i)) //Maps the values to the completeList TreeSet
    //Supposed to solve problem with mismatched types

  }
// this for loop returns Unit, it just iterates on elements, and you need to add return value for compile
}
else{

  completeList.map(i => (crooksListed(numCounted.indexOf(largestValue)), largestValue)) //Maps the values to the TreeSet
// in this place you return mapped cimpleteList as Tree, but be carefull it's empty
}
```

I think this sample could be something like this:

```
if (numValues > 1) { // Used JIC there are multiple instances of numValues
  for (i <- numCounted.indices) { //If there are multiple instances, find the indeces of them
    if (numCounted(i) == largestValue)
      indeces(i) //add the index to the array
  }
  indeces.map(w => crooksListed(w) -> w).foldLeft(TreeSet.empty[(String, Int)]){
    case (tree, pair) => tree + pair
  }
} else {
  completeList.map(i => (crooksListed(numCounted.indexOf(largestValue)), largestValue)) //Maps the values to the TreeSet
}
```

Here I'm fills empty tree in *true* branch by pairs from crooksListed and wow indeces and this branch return TreeSet like a *false* branch.
Try read more about expressions and try to use **recursion** instead of *for* and *while* loops.